# Postgres - the last version 0.14.0 of the "pg" gem gives error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pg

I have updated my bundler which contains **pg** gem and I got the error

```
An error occured while installing pg (0.14.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.14.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I have checked this gem on **rubygems.org** and today (June 23) was released this version. I don't know why, but the version doesn't works me correctly and return the error above.

The solution is set up the specific version - in this case

**gem "pg", "~> 0.13.2"**

Anyone with the same issue?

Comment: Did you try installing the gem without Bundler as the output suggests? If so, did that result in an error as well?

Comment: please look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564117/sudo-gem-install-pg-wont-work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application.

**You don't need to specify a specific version of PG in your Gemfile**

**So :**

```
sudo apt install ruby-dev libpq-dev build-essential
```