# Rails: Error installing pg gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Postgres - the last version 0.14.0 of the “pg” gem gives error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172264/postgres-the-last-version-0-14-0-of-the-pg-gem-gives-error)

I'm new to rails. I want to use PostgreSQL since Heroku uses it too, but I'm having a bad time installing the `pg` gem. Apparently, some files are missing and a Makefile cannot be created?

My gem file looks like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.6'
gem 'faker', '1.0.1'
gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
gem 'json'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.10.0'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.0'

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.4.0'
end
```

And when I run `bundle install` I get the following error when installing the pg gem:

```
    Installing pg (0.14.0) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/local/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pqlib
    --without-pqlib
    --with-libpqlib
    --without-libpqlib
    --with-ms/libpqlib
    --without-ms/libpqlib


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/KennyGWang/.bundler/tmp/18833/gems/pg-0.14.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/KennyGWang/.bundler/tmp/18833/gems/pg-0.14.0/ext/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing pg (0.14.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.14.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I installed postgresql using homebrew, `brew install postgresql`, thus `which psql` gives me `/usr/local/bin/psql`

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209797/cant-find-the-postgresql-client-library-libpq

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Are you on a Mac? If so - the easiest way to do this is to

1. make sure you have Xcode installed (you can get it from the app store)
2. use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)
3. `brew install postgresql`
4. `gem uninstall pg`
5. either `bundle install` in your application's root or `gem install pg`

Comment: Just a note on #1.  It's very important to have Xcode installed and working properly in order for the postgresql formula to work.  The compiler is used to build the PostgreSQL source.

Comment: Worked for me on Mac OSX Mountain Lion (10.8.3).

Comment: I tried this but didn't seem to work for me. This ended up being the solution that fixed it for me http://stackoverflow.com/a/26609483/1438478.

Comment: Just to add to this as I came across it searching Google, I had a similar problem on OSX Yosemite: the above didn't work for me but this did: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7497725/1945990

Comment: i just want to say that i am totally amazed this actually worked because usually postgres is a pile and takes forever to fix

Comment: On Ubuntu:
-> sudo apt-get install postgresql-client libpq5 libpq-dev
-> sudo gem install pg

Answer (score 10):

Steps to install postgresql

1. Install PostgreSQL and its libraries

   ```
   sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib libpq-dev
   ```
2. After the installation create a user for postgresql

   ```
   sudo -u postgres createuser --superuser $USER
   ```

   or

   ```
   sudo -u postgres createuser pgs_root
   ```
3. Set user password for the postgresql user

   ```
   sudo -u postgres psql postgres --set "user=$USER"
   postgres=# \passsword :user
   ```

   or

   ```
   sudo -u postgres psql postgres
   postgres=# \passsword pgs_root
   ```
4. Configure the postgresql.conf file to make PostgreSQL listen to localhost or listen on an external IP or something, change this line to either the IP or 'localhost'

   ```
   gedit /etc/postgresql/8.4/main/postgresql.conf listen_addresses = 'localhost'
   ```

---

Like mysql query browser, there is a GUI for postgresql called pgadmin. To install run this command

```
sudo apt-get install pgadmin3
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to include this instead of pg

```
gem install postgres-pr
```

or

```
gem install ruby-pg
```

Edit

Did you do this already?

```
$ sudo apt-get install postgresql

$ rails new pg -d postgres
```

> http://www.funonrails.com/2011/03/getting-started-with-rails-3-postgres.html

Comment: "sudo gem install ruby-pg" didn't work, but the first did.
I'm still missing this: "checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no"
i need the pg gem to run "rake db:migrate" !

Answer (score 0):

have you checked the log mkmf.log as it was recommended in the error you've included?

Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
 necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
 details.  You may need configuration options.