# heroku fails to take a rails application

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I am really bugged with a problem with Heroku. I am a total newbie and I have already tried out a few solutions and they don't seem to help me. Here is the error i get on using

```
group :development, :test do
gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

in the gem file this is the entry i have for sqlite 3

```
Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_2i8tok6rv3gyk/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /tmp/build_2i8tok6rv3gyk/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
   An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
   Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.7'` succeeds before bundling.
!
!     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
!     
!     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
!     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
!
!     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/Rails app

To git@heroku.com:glacial-wildwood-5205.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:glacial-wildwood-5205.git'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

heroku does not support `sqlite3` , use `Postgresql` instead.

```
group :development do
   gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :test, :production do
    gem 'pg'
end
```

In this way sqlite will be your local db , and postgres will be for test and production

Comment: how do i remove sqlite3 and add postgresql?

Comment: `Gem files will remain installed in /home/aravind/.bundler/tmp/15662/gems/pg-0.12.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/aravind/.bundler/tmp/15662/gems/pg-0.12.2/ext/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing pg (0.12.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.12.2'` succeeds before bundling`

This is the error i get when i did what you said. Please help.

Comment: also note that you may have to update some models to work properly in postgre

Comment: Hmm.. looks like you might need to install postgres? Check this question -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439207/rails-error-installing-pg-gem

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to change your Gemfile

add `gem 'pg'` to your production group

```
group :production do
  gem "pg"
end
```

Then be sure to run `bundle install` before you commit to heroku

This whole guide should help get you started: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby#using-a-sql-database