# Gem install encoding error after enironment changed from Win to Linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux

I am trying to install pgsql gem, but I have some strange encoding issue when trying to install. Whole app have just been migrated from windows environment to Linux environment, but only default gemfile was used. I have found that way to solve is to change locale in registry.rb, but as I mentioned, my environment is Linux. Gist of gem_make.out can be viewed here: [gist](https://gist.github.com/alankis/66fe0b3d80d0373dc01e)

postgresql is installed and runing:

```
$ service postgresql status 
9.3/main (port 5432): online
```

EDIT: Seems that this issue is only happening with pgsql gem, other gems are installing sucessfuly, for example, running `$ gem install A_123` installs specified gem successfully.

Comment: do you have pgsql installed in your system?

Comment: Yes, postgresql is installed and running.

Comment: $ sudo apt-get install ruby-dev libpq-dev build-essential
(Different problem, but probably the same solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172264/postgres-the-last-version-0-14-0-of-the-pg-gem-gives-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172264/postgres-the-last-version-0-14-0-of-the-pg-gem-gives-error) on SO, to which SO user grenierm5 pointed me,i t seems that installing ruby-dev headers for compiling extension modules did the trick.

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev && sudo gem install pg
```