# git push heroku master - can't push my site to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I can't push my site to heroku. Log is belove

```
Counting objects: 94, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (78/78), done.
Writing objects: 100% (94/94), 115.53 KiB, done.
Total 94 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0)


-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.2.1
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs bin/ --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from .........
       Fetching gem metadata from ..
       Installing rake (0.9.2.2)
       Installing i18n (0.6.1)
       Installing multi_json (1.3.6)
       Installing activesupport (3.2.8)
       Installing builder (3.0.4)
       Installing activemodel (3.2.8)
       Installing erubis (2.7.0)
       Installing journey (1.0.4)
       Installing rack (1.4.1)
       Installing rack-cache (1.2)
       Installing rack-test (0.6.2)
       Installing hike (1.2.1)
       Installing tilt (1.3.3)
       Installing sprockets (2.1.3)
       Installing actionpack (3.2.8)
       Installing mime-types (1.19)
       Installing polyglot (0.3.3)
       Installing treetop (1.4.11)
       Installing mail (2.4.4)
       Installing actionmailer (3.2.8)
       Installing arel (3.0.2)
       Installing tzinfo (0.3.33)
       Installing activerecord (3.2.8)
       Installing activeresource (3.2.8)
       Installing coffee-script-source (1.4.0)
       Installing execjs (1.4.0)
       Installing coffee-script (2.2.0)
       Installing rack-ssl (1.3.2)
       Installing json (1.7.5) with native extensions
       Installing rdoc (3.12)
       Installing thor (0.16.0)

       Installing railties (3.2.8)
       Installing coffee-rails (3.2.2)
       Installing jquery-rails (2.1.3)
       Using bundler (1.2.1)
       Installing rails (3.2.8)
       Installing sass (3.2.1)
       Installing sass-rails (3.2.5)
       Installing sqlite3 (1.3.6) with native extensions
```

First error

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
       /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
       checking for sqlite3.h... no
       sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
       or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
       location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
       *** extconf.rb failed ***
       Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
       necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
       details.  You may need configuration options.
       Provided configuration options:
       --with-opt-dir
       --without-opt-dir
       --with-opt-include
       --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
       --with-opt-lib
       --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
       --with-make-prog
       --without-make-prog
       --srcdir=.
       --curdir
       --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby
       --with-sqlite3-dir
       --without-sqlite3-dir
       --with-sqlite3-include
       --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
       --with-sqlite3-lib
       --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
       --enable-local
```

In this block error

```
    --disable-local
       Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_2tmilsljpykpx/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6 for inspection.
       Results logged to /tmp/build_2tmilsljpykpx/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
       An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
       Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.6'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !     
 !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
 !     http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/how-do-i-use-sqlite3-for-development
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app

To git@heroku.com:afternoon-shelf-6957.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:afternoon-shelf-6957.git'
```

Sorry for this section
Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly.
Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly.
Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly.
Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly.

```
$ sudo bundle install

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb 
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby1.8
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/pg-0.14.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/pg-0.14.1/ext/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing pg (0.14.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.14.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

GemFile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

#gem 'rails', '3.0.9'

#gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.6', :group => :development


gem 'rails', '3.2.8'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'json'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'


group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end


# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug'
```

Comment: as I know heroku doesnot support sqlite3 support yet use postgres database of heroku for that matter

Comment: I don't think they will ever support sqlite. That would be like them supporting Microsoft Access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

heroku works on `pg` and you are using sqlite3 so that error comes

try this and add into your gem file

```
group :production do
 gem 'pg'
end
group :development do
  # whatever you use - mysql or any other
end
```

Comment: I have error :) Log is upper.

Comment: see - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564117/sudo-gem-install-pg-wont-work

Comment: @user1776681 You still have a stray gem "sqlite" in your edit above.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku does not support SQLite databases - you should switch over to using Postgresql if you wish to use Heroku.

In you **Gemfile** replace

```
    gem 'sqlite3'
```

with

```
    gem 'pg'
```

You may also need to install Postgresql locally for development. Go to [www.postgresql.org](http://www.postgresql.org) for help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku uses PostgreSQL and doesn't support other databases, including sqlite3.

They have a guide on setting up PostgreSQL locally:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-postgresql