# Not able to install pg gem on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ruby, rubygems, postgresql-9.1, pg, ubuntu-12.10

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit and I have following packages installed :

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep postgre
```

output:

```
postgresql
postgresql-9.1
postgresql-client
postgresql-client-9.1
postgresql-client-common
postgresql-common
postgresql-contrib
postgresql-contrib-9.1
postgresql-server-dev-9.1
postgresql-server-dev-all
libpq-dev
libpq5
```

`rvm 1.17.9`

`ruby 1.9.3p362 (2012-12-25 revision 38607) [x86_64-linux]`

I am not able to install pg gem I am getting following error :

```
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /home/vedarthk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
```

I have also tried following commands but the output is same as above :

```
gem install pg -- --with-pg-include=/usr/include/postgresql/libpq --with-pg-lib=/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/lib


gem install pg -- --with-pg-include=/usr/include/postgresql --with-pg-lib=/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/lib
```

Comment: Try installing `build-essential` package as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12269483/429758. The other answers in that thread - particularly the ones about `rvmsudo` - might help as well.

Comment: I did do that but `build-essential` is already installed and I have latest version.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing PostgreSQL development headers:

sudo apt-get install libpq-dev

Comment: Duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116015/how-to-install-gem-pg-on-ubuntuXX

Comment: @vedarthk already indicates that they've this package installed. This can't be the answer. (And therefore is not a duplicate question)

Answer (score 0):

Try -
$ sudo apt-get install ruby-dev

[sudo gem install pg won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564117/sudo-gem-install-pg-wont-work) has that solution and it worked for me.

Comment: I am using rvm, using `sudo apt-get install ruby-dev` gives me an error `ruby-dev : Depends: ruby1.9.1-dev (>= 1.9.3.194-1) but it is not going to be installed`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on RHEL 6.4, the following worked for me:

```
gem install /opt/redmine/vendor/cache/pg-0.18.4.gem --local -- --with-pg-dir=/usr/pgsql-9.4/
```

I setup PostgreSQL from their own repos.